How to remove indent and increase vertical space inside a chapter of memoir class?
I am writing the acknowledgment in my thesis
\documentclass{memoir}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}

\noindent
I would like to thank A

\vspace{0.3cm}

\noindent
I would like to thank B

\vspace{0.3cm}

\noindent
I would like to thank C

\end{document}

The content of my acknowledgment is
I would like to thank A

I would like to thank B

I would like to thank C

Could you explain how to systematically remove indent and increase vertical space (between paragraphs) in this section?


Do you want this throughout the whole document or just within this section?

@AlanMunn I want it throughout only in this section.

You can use the \abnormalparskip command to set a special value for parskip, and set the \parindent to 0. If you do this all within a group, i.e., enclosed in {...} it will apply locally.
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\begin{document}

\chapter*{Acknowledgment}
{
\abnormalparskip{0.3cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

I would like to thank A

I would like to thank B

I would like to thank C
}
\chapter{A chapter}
\kant[1-2]


\end{document}


Thank you very much for your help!
